# Should I rely heavily on keeping references?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a relatively large GUI based OOP software (in Python) were I rely heavily on keeping references throughout the program. For example I would define a Main class with some stored options as an attribute (code example below). In a second class, e.g. OptionFrame I would pass the reference to that stored options object and store it again as an attribute. This has the great advantage that if I change the stored options in OptionFrame it will also be changed in Main. However recently I skrewed up the whole program by writting a function that reinitializes the stored options and therefore gives it a new reference, like reset_options_bad in the example below. Therefore the two option objects in OptionFrame and Main were no longer connected and my program did not work anymore.

Was this design decision to rely heavily on passing references around and relying on them a good idea?

```
Class OptionFrame:
    def __init__(self,options):
        self.options=options

    def change_options(self):
        self.options['example']=False # This should also change the options in main

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stored_options = {'example':True}   
        self.option_frame = OptionFrame(self.stored_options)

    def reset_options_bad(self):
        self.stored_options = {'example':True} # This is a bad idea

    def reset_options_good(self):
        self.stored_options.clear()
        self.stored_options.update({'example':True})
        self.stored_options
```

Comment: Not in python. You are basically stuck with testing for `Main.stored_options is Main.options_frame.options` everywhere

Comment: @Caleth Thanks that is a good idea at least. But what to do if the test returns false?

Comment: Fail fast. Throw an exception detailing what you operation did that, let the process exit, see a failing test. something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960616/2610810) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

What you basically have is a global variable in disguise.  And all the problems of global variables apply.  It even gets extra fun when you add a new the reference and you effectively *add* another global variable.

So I would say it is not a good idea.

Comment: What design pattern would you propose instead?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your situation, my first inclination is toward dependency injection.  Inject some kind of service which gets config values (the values themselves, not the object that holds everything).  Then if something changes, it returns the correct value.  Added benefit that the backing storage can change and the dependent code never needs to know or care.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a Context object.  Isn't a Context object really just a global variable that's being handed around?

Comment: @RobertHarvey OP basically *has* the context object already (Only difference to here is `Main` is creating it, rather than receiving it).

Comment: So you're saying that a "global variable" is OK, so long as you're injecting it.

Comment: no, I'm saying @Becuzz's suggestion isn't an improvement

Comment: @Caleth There is an important difference.  With a global variable, it is very hard to control what people do with it, including how they modify it.  Which is what leads to crazy bugs where one piece of code happened to run at an unexpected time, changed the variable and things blew up.  With an injected service, you can easily control how your config values / other shared state are accessed.  If you don't want to allow any modification, don't.  Then it's effectively a constant.  If you allow modification, it's much easier to control how.  Also easier to find where it happens. (cont.)

Comment: @Caleth In projects of any decent size, there is going to be some global state, whether that's connection strings, API urls, license keys, etc.  The trick is controlling how much of it can be mutated.  The less, the better.  But if you absolutely have to have mutatable global state, it would be better to have one controllable access point rather than just letting it run wild.

Comment: @Becuzz OP has the problem that python doesn't have much stopping you from rebinding a name. All you have suggested is moving the creation of `stored_options` up the object creation graph (and probably changing all OP's code from `options['key']` to `... = options.get('key')` / `options.set('key', ...)`). That's orthogonal to "be vigilant about rebinding names"

Comment: @Caleth I'll be the first to declare that I am no Python expert.  I don't know what Python's capabilities are.  It's up to the OP to decide if a dependency injection route makes sense for his application (or language).  He just asked for a suggestion and I made one.